# Manga about enslaved gnomes forced to transcribe books

Tags: story-identification, manga

Fantasy setting(of course). The first chapter introduces a group of gnomes that have been enslaved and forced to transcribe books from some other world. Things happen, and the entire library's worth of gnomes excluding the main character are killed.

I saw this a little less than a year ago.

Almost certain that either the title, or the main characters's name starts with a B.

Also, the cover is a closeup of the main character's face, and is very red.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Please check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you remember any additional details to [edit] into your question.

Comment: Was it *about* "enslaved gnomes forced to transcribe books" or did this merely show up as a plot point in a larger world?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: @Valorum It was more of a plot point at the very beginning.

Answer (score 3):

**童子軍鑑 ([*Douji Gunkan*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=152172))** by Oda Serina.

[image: Manga cover fo volume 1]

Description from MangaUpdates:

> Fei is a **gnome**, a race of small stature and high intelligence. With the **promise of freedom**, he works until dawn to read and **translate the mysterious ancient documents that have suddenly appeared from another world**. That is how it should have been, however, a **turn of fate** sets him on a path of revenge.
>
> (emphasis mine)

The "turn of fate" follows this premise stated in the question (according to the review in Japanese that I read),

> Things happen, and the entire library's worth of gnomes excluding the main character are killed.

---

Found by googling `ノーム 図書館 死亡 漫画` (gnome, library, death, manga) which returned [the review/spoiler of the 1st chapter in Japanese](https://amuse-labo.com/doujigunkan-1/).

Comment: I know you aren't supposed to do this probably, but I didn't wanna leave anybody hanging here. Couldn't get back into the account I made this with. Anyways, that was it. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @Hankbastank Please follow [these instructions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) to get your previous account back and accept Andrew's answer :)